C and infinity arithmetic
#include <math.h>

void main() {
    double a = 0;
    a += 5e308;
    a -= 3.5e308;

    if (a == INFINITY) {
        printf("1   %e\n", a);
    }
    else
        printf("0   %e\n", a);
}

Here, the first print line is what I expect but why is the second print statement executed?
I think a should be positive infinity as infinity -3.5e308 should be positive infinity, right in line 4?
I have already tried to execute it but the output is:
0   -1.#IND00e+000

I would like to know where my logic goes wrong.

I'd guess that a += 5e308; gives you infinity but when you then try to use it in a -= 3.5e308; it becomes a NAN (not a number).

Look up the FP classification macros such as isfinite(), isinf(), isnan().  Consider using them.

The incorrect assumption that you seem to have is that (double) INFINITY - 3.5e308 would result in positive infinity.
Since 3.5e308 exceeds the range of double, it is a floating-point infinity. Both GCC and Clang, with no added compiler flags, provide a warning that both of those large values are too large for the type double.
The result is then effectively:
double a = (double) 0 + (double) INFINITY - (double) INFINITY;

It doesn't matter that, numerically, 3.5e308 is smaller than 5e308. Both are a double-precision infinity.
The subtraction of infinity from infinity is defined to result in a NaN.

So, I should be getting 1.#QNAN0e+000 but why am I getting -1. #INF00e+000

@HariHaran What you've shown says -1.#IND00e+000, not -1.#INF00e+000. From the Microsoft documentation, the result when printing "Indefinite (same as quiet NaN)" is: "digit .#IND random-digits".

It also indicates that this is the format used in the CRT in pre-2015 Visual Studio. This has since been fixed to use the standard-compliant nan(ind) to represent an "indefinite" result.

https://godbolt.org/z/xb5oWGPz7 shows building with a recent version of GCC. it displays wanings when compiling and the expected NaN in the output.  interesting to me as somehow I'd not noticed that NaN was signed before!
